# Scraping data from the web

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape prices, miles and models of different cars from truecar.com. I think, I find appropriate tags from the website, but my code doesn't give me the suitable data. My code gives me empty data and I do not find the problem. How can I fix this?

I receive "unexpected indent" when defining price, miles and model.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector
url='https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

data = []
for card in soup.select('[class="card-content vehicle-card-body order-3 vehicle-card-carousel-
body"]'):
    price = card.select_one('[class="heading-3 margin-y-1 font-weight-bold"]').text

    miles = card.select_one('div[class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between"]').text

    models=card.select_one('div[class="vehicle-card-top"]').text

    data.append({'price':price,'miles':miles,'models':models})

print(data)
```

Comment: That code would not produce an "unexpected indent" error.  Perhaps you should post the actual code, plus the exact text of the error.

Comment: @TimRoberts, How I can send you the pic of my vscode?

Comment: @TimRoberts, you are right. In vscode, it runs, but dose not print data

Comment: Is there actually a newline after "`vehicle-card-carousel-`"? Or was it copied from a terminal window or similar? E.g., with a width of 100 that is "dash"-aware? Or the dash just happened to be at position 94? Or on the contrary, that was the reason for the "unexpected indent"? Did you copy the code from somewhere else?

Comment: There is the same problem in the code you [posted two days earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73397649/insert-data-into-a-table-mysql). Plus indentation problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following selectors to fetch the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/'
r=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

cards = soup.select('div.linkable.card.card-shadow.vehicle-card._1qd1muk')

data = []
for card in cards:
    vehicleCardYearMakeModel = card.find("div", {"data-test" : "vehicleCardYearMakeModel"}).text.replace('Sponsored', '')
    vehicleMileage = card.find("div", {"data-test" : "vehicleMileage"}).text
    vehiclePrice = card.find("div", {"data-test" : "vehicleCardPricingBlockPrice"}).text
    data.append({'price':vehiclePrice,'miles':vehicleMileage,'models':vehicleCardYearMakeModel})
```

which gives you the expected output

```
[{'price': '$48,499', 'miles': '33,544 miles', 'models': '2018 BMW X5'}, {'price': '$19,900', 'miles': '76,418 miles', 'models': '2018 Chevrolet Equinox'}, {'price': '$48,795', 'miles': '40,551 miles', 'models': '2018 BMW 7 Series'}, {'price': '$14,445', 'miles': '169,206 miles', 'models': '2019 Nissan Rogue'}, {'price': '$21,174', 'miles': '22 miles', 'models': '2020 Kia Optima'}, {'price': '$9,680', 'miles': '126,555 miles', 'models': '2013 Honda Civic'}, {'price': '$19,300', 'miles': '21,467 miles', 'models': '2020 Toyota Corolla'}, {'price': '$22,000', 'miles': '35,453 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Malibu'}, {'price': '$10,562', 'miles': '214,543 miles', 'models': '2018 Chevrolet Equinox'}, {'price': '$17,997', 'miles': '51,278 miles', 'models': '2020 Nissan Altima'}, {'price': '$70,788', 'miles': '5,854 miles', 'models': '2022 Ford Super Duty F-250'}, {'price': '$21,500', 'miles': '15,230 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Equinox'}, {'price': '$12,999', 'miles': '148,605 miles', 'models': '2018 Ford Escape'}, {'price': '$30,683', 'miles': '51,273 miles', 'models': '2018 Ford F-150'}, {'price': '$10,849', 'miles': '85,539 miles', 'models': '2015 Nissan Altima'}, {'price': '$12,522', 'miles': '118,858 miles', 'models': '2014 Ford Fusion'}, {'price': '$18,995', 'miles': '65,156 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Malibu'}, {'price': '$19,497', 'miles': '61,376 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Malibu'}, {'price': '$17,700', 'miles': '53,012 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Malibu'}, {'price': '$51,775', 'miles': '15,204 miles', 'models': '2021 Toyota Tundra'}, {'price': '$16,977', 'miles': '67,389 miles', 'models': '2019 Dodge Grand Caravan'}, {'price': '$18,900', 'miles': '75,023 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Malibu'}, {'price': '$18,000', 'miles': '53,271 miles', 'models': '2020 Chevrolet Malibu'}, {'price': '$20,900', 'miles': '182,907 miles', 'models': '2018 Ford F-150'}, {'price': '$15,909', 'miles': '84,249 miles', 'models': '2020 Toyota Corolla'}, {'price': '$18,836', 'miles': '69,731 miles', 'models': '2019 Dodge Grand Caravan'}, {'price': '$9,995', 'miles': '119,941 miles', 'models': '2015 Chrysler 200'}, {'price': '$20,998', 'miles': '36,529 miles', 'models': '2017 Chevrolet Silverado 1500'}, {'price': '$6,800', 'miles': '158,894 miles', 'models': '2015 Nissan Altima'}, {'price': '$11,666', 'miles': '83,328 miles', 'models': '2014 Ford Fusion'}, {'price': '$7,670', 'miles': '64,000 miles', 'models': '2015 Ford Focus'}, {'price': '$16,995', 'miles': '180,663 miles', 'models': '2018 Ford F-150'}, {'price': '$20,990', 'miles': '138,684 miles', 'models': '2016 Ford F-150'}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to put this info in a table in mysql. I use this code:   `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                                  host='127.0.0.1',
                                  database='cars')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
for entry in data:
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO car(Model,Mileage,Price) VALUES(\'%s\',\'%s\,\'%s\')"%(entry['models'],entry['miles'],entry['price']))
     cnx.commit()
cnx.close()`  if you see any problem with this code, please tell me.

Comment: @Ali, glad, I could help you

Comment: @Ali sorry I did not see your updated comment, but I don't see any error with your code, but in any case if you experience any error while running the code you can ask a question here and I ll try to look into the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you won’t get any result is that there is a *whitespace* in one of you class names in the first selection.

So there is nothing to iterate and your *for* loop won’t start. Fix this and you will get your results from the rest of your code:

```
soup.select('[class="card-content vehicle-card-body order-3 vehicle-card-carousel-body"]
```

instead of:

```
soup.select('[class="card-content vehicle-card-body order-3 vehicle-card-carousel- body"]
```

Comment: The white space is a newline, at least as posted in the question.